# $T(B) = AB − BA$. Find the matrix for $T$ with respect to the standard basis of $M_{2\times 2} (\mathbb R)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Question: Let $A\in M _{2\times 2} (\mathbb R)$ be fixed and define $T: M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R) \to  M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ by
> $$T(B) = AB − BA.$$
> Show that $T$ is linear. Find the matrix for $T$ with respect to the standard basis $\beta$ of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$.

I'm done with showing the linear part, my query here is while finding the transformation matrix will the answer be dependent on our choice of $A$ matrix.

For example, taking
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We get
$$
T\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
\right) = (0,\beta,\gamma,0)
$$
Similarly, all the basis transformations will be dependent on elements of $A$. Will the answer be $A$ dependent?

Comment: Yes, of course it will.

Comment: @AtomBomb Yes, the answer will be $A$-dependent. The point is to write the matrix in terms of the entries of $A$.

Comment: Ohh okay thanks

Answer (score 2):

To correct your example, we should have
$$
T\left[ \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} \right] = 
\pmatrix{\alpha&0\\\gamma&0} - 
\pmatrix{\alpha & \beta\\0&0} = \pmatrix{0&-\beta\\\gamma & 0}.
$$
Now, it's not totally clear what the "standard" basis of $M_{2\times 2}$ is supposed to be, but I would guess that you're referring to the basis
$$
\mathcal B = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\} =\\
\left\{
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}, \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
\right\}.
$$
If that is the case, then the above example shows that the coordinate vector of $T(v_1)$ is given by $[T(v_1)]_{\mathcal B} = (0,-\beta,\gamma, 0)$. This gives you the first column of the transformation matrix, which is to say that the matrix of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal B$ has the form
$$
[T]_{\mathcal B} = 
\pmatrix{0&?&?&?\\
-\beta &?&?&?\\
\gamma&?&?&?\\
0&?&?&?
}.
$$
Once you have done this for each element of $\mathcal B$, you should find that the full matrix is given by
$$
[T]_{\mathcal B} = (A \otimes I) - (I \otimes A^\top) = 
\pmatrix{
0 & - \gamma & \beta & 0\\- \beta & \alpha - \delta & 0 & \beta\\\gamma & 0 & - \alpha + \delta & - \gamma\\0 & \gamma & - \beta & 0
}.
$$
In the above formula, $I$ is a size-2 identity matrix and $\otimes$ denotes a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

---

For anyone who might find this useful: here is a Python script that gets the answer for $[T]_{\mathcal B}$ above using both the systematic approach (to get `ans_1`) and the Kronecker product formula (to get `ans_2`).

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

a,b,c,d = sp.symbols('alpha beta gamma delta')
A = sp.Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]])
ans = []

for i in range(4):
    B = sp.Matrix.zeros(4,1)
    B[i] = 1
    B = B.reshape(2,2)
    ans.append((A@B - B@A).reshape(4,1))

ans_1 = sp.Matrix.hstack(*ans)
ans_2 = sp.Matrix(np.kron(A,sp.eye(2)) - np.kron(sp.eye(2),A.T))
print(ans_1 - ans_2)
```

Comment: How do we get the formula you used?

Comment: @AtomBomb Given the nature of the question, I would guess that the formula (and the Kronecker product for that matter) is not something you'll encounter in the course you're taking. If you're still curious though, the formula is a consequence of the properties of row-major [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)). Note: the Wikipedia article is about column-major vectorization, which corresponds to a different "standard basis" for $M_{2\times 2}$.

Comment: @AtomBomb The relevant formula for row-major vectorization is 
$$
\operatorname{vec}(PQ) = (P \otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(Q) = (I \otimes Q^\top)\operatorname{vec}(P).
$$